# Retrieve list of inverse document frequencies from words in Elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm interested in retrieving a list of inverse document frequency (idf) for all words available in a certain index. Is this possible to do by querying the index, or should I rather do this outside of elasticsearch? If so, do how do you propose I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue, searched and found interesting feature [Top hits Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation). This maybe your answer.